# ASP .Net SignalR not calling client's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr

I've been using asp .net SignalR and my web application index page was working good with SignalR, but when I started making details page using this push notifications system I've got error - SignalR is not calling my client's method on details page.

Here's my **details** page code using razor:

```
<h2>last bidders</h2>
<table class="table-info" style="width: 500px;">
    <thead>
        <th>bidder</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>time</th>
        <th>state</th>
    </thead>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i < ViewBag.count) // Bidder exists
        {
            <tr>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("bidder" + i)">@ViewBag.bidders[i]</td>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("price" + i)">@ViewBag.prices[i]</td>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("time" + i)">@ViewBag.times[i]</td>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("state" + i)">@ViewBag.states[i]</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else // No bidder - fill with blank
        {
            <tr>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("bidder" + i)">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("price" + i)">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("time" + i)">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="@Html.Raw("state" + i)">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        }
    } 
</table>

<input type="hidden" id="IDAuction" value="@ViewBag.IDAuction" />

@section scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>        
    $(function () {

        var my_hub = $.connection.myHub;

        my_hub.client.auctionDetailsUpdate = function (IDAuction, newBidder, newPrice, newTime, newState) {
            alert("auctionDetailsUpdate()");
            var x = document.getElementById("IDAuction").value;
            alert('1');
            if (x == IDAuction) {
                alert('2');
                moveRowsDown();
                alert('3');
                document.getElementById("time0").innerHTML = newTime;
                document.getElementById("price0").innerHTML = newPrice;
                document.getElementById("bidder0").innerHTML = newBidder;
                document.getElementById("state0").innerHTML = newState;
                alert('4');
            }
        };

        // Client register on MyHub
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //my_hub.server.registerConId($("#clientEmail").val());
            });
        });

    });

    function moveRowsDown() {
        alert('moverowsdown')
        for (var i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
            document.getElementById("time" + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById("time" + (i - 1)).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("price" + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById("price" + (i - 1)).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("bidder" + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById("bidder" + (i - 1)).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("state" + i).innerHTML = document.getElementById("state" + (i - 1)).innerHTML;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here's my **index** page (I've put only relevant code to SignalR, I've tried not to fill my question with useless information in code):

```
@section scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {

        var my_hub = $.connection.myHub;

        // Server reply on bid attempt
        my_hub.client.clientBidsUpdate = function (IDAuction, newState, newDuration, newLastBidder, newPrice, warningNoTokens) {
            var clientEmail = $("#" + "email" + IDAuction).val();
            $("#" + "state" + IDAuction).text(newState);
            $("#" + "time" + IDAuction).text(newDuration);
            $("#" + "price" + IDAuction).text(newPrice);
            // Unsuccessful bid
            if (warningNoTokens == "true") {
                if (newLastBidder == clientEmail) {
                    alert("Not enough tokens to place bigger bid. Please buy some tokens!");
                }
            // Succesful bid
            } else {
                $("#" + "lastbidder" + IDAuction).text(newLastBidder);
                $("#" + "spanPrice" + IDAuction).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up");
                $("#" + "spanPrice2" + IDAuction).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up");
            }
        };

        // Increase previous bidder token number - someone has bigger bid
        my_hub.client.setTokenNumber = function (clientSelector, tokenNumber, clientAlertSelector) {
            document.getElementById(clientSelector).innerHTML = tokenNumber;
            document.getElementById(clientAlertSelector).style.display = "inline-block";
        }

        // Timer Update method // each 1 second
        my_hub.client.timerUpdate = function (IDAuction, newState, newDuration, newLastBidder, newPrice) {
            $("#" + "state" + IDAuction).text(newState);
            $("#" + "time" + IDAuction).text(newDuration);
            $("#" + "lastbidder" + IDAuction).text(newLastBidder);
            $("#" + "price" + IDAuction).text(newPrice);
            // Disable auction on client side
            if (newState == "Sold" || newState == "Expired") {
                if (newState == "Sold") {
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).html("Sold");
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).removeClass("btn-warning btn").addClass("btn-info btn");
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).css("background-color", "blueviolet");
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).css("color", "white");
                    $("#" + "state" + IDAuction).css("color", "blueviolet");
                    $("#" + "spanLastBidder" + IDAuction).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-user").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#" + "picture" + IDAuction).css("-webkit-filter", "blur(8px)").css("filter", "blur(8px)");
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else if (newState == "Expired") { 
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).html("Expired");
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).removeClass("btn-warning btn").addClass("btn-default btn");
                    $("#" + "state" + IDAuction).css("color", "rgb(255, 54, 40)");
                    $("#" + "spanLastBidder" + IDAuction).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-user").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#" + "picture" + IDAuction).css("-webkit-filter", "blur(8px)").css("filter", "blur(8px)");
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).prop("disabled", true);
                    $("#" + "btn" + IDAuction).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 54, 40)");
                }
            }
            $("#" + "spanPrice" + IDAuction).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up");
            $("#" + "spanPrice2" + IDAuction).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up");
            var clientEmail = document.getElementById("clientEmail").value;
            var clientEmailReplaced = clientEmail.replace("@@", "_");
            document.getElementById("alertToken" + clientEmailReplaced).style.display = "none";
        };

        // Client sends bid to Server
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('.btnBid').click(function (event) {
                var idBtnJquery = $(event.target).attr('id');
                var IDAuc = idBtnJquery.substring(3, idBtnJquery.length);
                var clientEmail = $("#" + "email" + IDAuc).val();
                my_hub.server.send(IDAuc, clientEmail);
            });
        });

        // Client register on MyHub
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                my_hub.server.registerConId($("#clientEmail").val());
            });
        });

    });

    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }

    // Variables
    var toolbarVisible = false;

    // Search - Menu toolbar preview
    $("#showHideBtn").click(function () {
        $("#menuSearchToolbar").slideToggle("slow", "swing");
        if (toolbarVisible == true) {
            toolbarVisible = false;
            $("#showHideBtn").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
        } else {
            toolbarVisible = true;
            $("#showHideBtn").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up");
        }                
    });

</script>
}
```

Here's my **hub server class**

```
namespace IEP_Projekat.Hubs
{

public static class mutex
{
    public static string lockObject = "MutEx";
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> hashUsersConnIds = new Dictionary<string, string>(512);

    public void Send(long IDAuc, string lastBidderEmail)
    {
        lock (mutex.lockObject)
        {
            if ((productNewPrice <= user.TokenNumber))
            {       
                if (previousBidderID != null)
                {         
                    if (hashUsersConnIds.ContainsKey(previous.Email))
                    {
                        Clients.Client(hashUsersConnIds[previous.Email]).setTokenNumber(clientSelector, newTokenCount, clientAlertSelector);
                    }  
                    if (previous.Email != lastBidderEmail && hashUsersConnIds.ContainsKey(lastBidderEmail)) {
                        Clients.Client(hashUsersConnIds[lastBidderEmail]).setTokenNumber(clientSelector, newBidderCount, clientAlertSelector);
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    if (hashUsersConnIds.ContainsKey(lastBidderEmail))
                    {
                        Clients.Client(hashUsersConnIds[lastBidderEmail]).setTokenNumber(clientSelector, newBidderCount, clientAlertSelector);
                    }
                }

                Clients.All.clientBidsUpdate(IDAuc, auction.state, remainingToEnd, lastBidderEmail, auction.price + auction.increment, "false");
                Clients.All.auctionDetailsUpdate(IDAuc, lastBidderEmail, auction.price + auction.increment, newBid.bidTime, "Open");
                return;

            }

            else if (auction.lastbidder == user.Email)
            {
                if (user.TokenNumber > 0) // can place next bid
                {
                    if (hashUsersConnIds.ContainsKey(lastBidderEmail))
                    {
                        Clients.Client(hashUsersConnIds[lastBidderEmail]).setTokenNumber(clientSelector, user.TokenNumber, clientAlertSelector);
                    }

                    Clients.All.clientBidsUpdate(IDAuc, auction.state, remainingToEnd, lastBidderEmail, auction.price + auction.increment, "false");
                    Clients.All.auctionDetailsUpdate(IDAuc, lastBidderEmail, auction.price + auction.increment, newBid.bidTime, "Open");                      
                    return;
                }
            }

            Clients.All.clientBidsUpdate(IDAuc, auction.state, remaining, lastBidderEmail, auction.price + auction.increment, "true");
        }
    }

    // Registring client
    public void registerConId(string email)
    {
        hashUsersConnIds[email] = Context.ConnectionId;
    }

}

public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {          
        Schedule(() =>
        {
            lock (mutex.lockObject)
            {
                var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
                foreach (var auction in auctionsList)
                {
                    if (now >= end)
                    {

                        if (edited.increment == 0)
                        {
                            hubContext.Clients.All.timerUpdate(auction.IDAuc, edited.state, newDurationExpired, " - ", edited.price);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hubContext.Clients.All.timerUpdate(auction.IDAuc, edited.state, newDurationSold, edited.lastbidder, soldPrice);
                            hubContext.Clients.All.auctionDetailsUpdate(auction.IDAuc, edited.lastbidder, soldPrice, newDurationSold, "Sold");                               
                        }
                    }
                    hubContext.Clients.All.timerUpdate(auction.IDAuc, auction.state, newDuration, auction.lastbidder, actualPrice);
                }
            }
        }).ToRunNow().AndEvery(1).Seconds();
    }
}
}
```

Here's my server logic. I've using MyHub.cs as hub class, and Registry as timer. I've cleaned code of database accesses and some calculations because that part has no problem, and I've wanted to avoid putting 350 lines of code, so I've just left important code in this SignalR interactions.

**I've got problems with Clients.All.auctionDetailsUpdate**(...), while debugging web application it says everything's fine, and other method SignalR methods works, but I don't get any alert from my Details page specified in auctionDetailsUdate() method like it for some reason Hub hasn't called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by implementing method's that are being called on client (javascript).

So I've added (with blank bodies) on details.cshtml

```
my_hub.client.timerUpdate = function (IDAuction, newState, newDuration, newLastBidder, newPrice) { }
my_hub.client.setTokenNumber = function (clientSelector, tokenNumber, clientAlertSelector) { }
my_hub.client.clientBidsUpdate = function (IDAuction, newState, newDuration, newLastBidder, newPrice, warningNoTokens) { }
```

And it seems that problem was that SignalR needs to have implemented all javascript methods on view pages even they've got blank bodies.